# JQuery get the value from <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to get the value from the `<li>` in JQuery click event.
I'm using an unordered list as a selection table in place of a real dropdown list.

HTML:

```
<ul id="dropdown">
 <li value="1">user name</li>
 <li value="2">user age</li>
 <li value="3">user height</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('#contactdiv1 #dropdown li').click(function(e) {
      var selection = $(this).text(); //this alerts name
      var selection = $(this).value(); // this fails object undefined
      var selection = $(this).find("value").text(); // this is blank
      alert(selection);
     //populateTableRow($('#customer-title'), data, selection);
});
```

Comment: `li` doesn't have `value` property so `.value()` will not work. Try `attr("value")` instead

Comment: use $(this).attr("value")

Comment: Use a `data-*` attribute instead (such as `data-value`). I don't think that the `value` attribute is valid on `li` elements. The `value` attribute is meant for `input` elements.

Comment: remove the `value` from `<li>` and use data attributes
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: @vsync `.value()` won't work at all because it would be `.val()`

Comment: I would like to use proper html so are you saying: use `data-value="1"`?

Comment: @BarclayVision - yes. `data-value` is the way envisioned by W3C

Comment: @Andreas - can you explain, how .val() will work?

Comment: @RanjitSingh In this case? Not at all :) Only if it would be an input element, then you would use `.val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get attribute using .attr value works on form/input elements its not a valid attribute for li

```js
$('#dropdown li').click(function(e) {
     alert($(this).attr("value"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="dropdown">
 <li value="1">user name</li>
 <li value="2">user age</li>
 <li value="3">user height</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is what I'm looking for, and your example works great, but its not working in mine??? - could it be a parent/child thing ???

Comment: selector may be #dropdown li and you're #contactdiv1 #dropdown li just make sure html is perfect

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should not be using `value` attribute on `<ul>` it is reserved only for `<ol>`.

You could allways use `$("selector").attr("attribute")` to get the value of any attribute present in your element.

As told in the comments, you should be using a `data-*` attribute for everything that is not pure HTML.